# Connection exception to port 9000 of localhost in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I have installed hadoop on my system. Now I start hadoop by following command:

```
     sbin/start-all.sh
```

I have checked jps command, I got following output:

```
645 DataNode
757 SecondaryNameNode
886 ResourceManager
2631 Jps
985 NodeManager
236
```

Now while I want to copy a file from my local file system to hdfs, i am getting following error:

```
Call From <my machine name>/192.168.0.101 to to localhost:9000 failed on 
connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused;
```

I am using mac. I think I have to open port 9000 on my system. I have found a few articles on internet, but did not find how to open a particular port in mac.

Answer (score 0):

In local installations, you should be running NameNode instead of SecondaryNameNode.

Connection refused means your PC does not listen on port 9000. Default port for NameNode is 8020, so you either specified wrong port in `fs.default.name` property, or your namenode is not running correctly.

Check your NameNode logs and if it runs, just specify correct port for connections.